# jQuery's "uploadProgress" not firing in "$.ajax"

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, progress-bar

I am new to jQuery and now, I am currently working on file uploads. And I want to add some progress bar each time I upload image. I used  the `uploadProgress` in jQuery but it seems doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
$('#_form_').on('submit', function(e){

   var file_and_desc = new FormData($(this)[0]),
       form_url = "_pages/_form_";

       var ext = choose.val(),
           allowed = ['jpg','png'];

       if(ext){
          var get_ext = ext.split('.');
              get_ext.reverse();

              if($.inArray(get_ext[0].toLowerCase(), allowed) > -1){
                   //upload image
                   $.ajax({
                         url : form_url,
                         type: 'POST',
                         data: file_and_desc,
                         contentType: false,
                         processData: false,
                         uploadProgress: function(event, positio, total, percentComplete){
                          $('h1').html(percentComplete);
                         },
                         success: function(data){
                              // some code here...
                         }
                   });
              }
       }
});
```

That's it! What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cleanest way to get the progress of JQuery ajax request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126994/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-progress-of-jquery-ajax-request)

Comment: @Villa7_, You're confusing my mind! It doesn't help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) reference, `uploadProgress` is not a valid option.

Instead, the `xhr` option is used instead, which lets you set progress listeners on the `XMLHttpRequest` that is used by the ajax request.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19127053) shows how to do that:

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
                //Do something with upload progress here
            }
       }, false);
       return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/",
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        //Do something on success
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much bud! Saved my day.

Comment: I think it is a valid reference if you have the jQuery form plugin installed. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: I noticed that you created the xhr object using "window.XMLHttpRequest" rather than just simply "XMLHttpRequest".  That was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.